# WSO2 EI - 6.6.0 https request CLOSE_WAIT

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, apache-axis, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have a problem with wso2 EI 6.6.0.
I send a https request to wso2 (soap proxy services) with a connection:close header. calls the endpoint and returns a response to the client. problem is - the connection remains in the close_wait state on the server (linux) (telnet | grep CLOSE_WAIT) and with each new call, the number of connections in the close_wait state will increase.

only solution is add this parameters to service.

```
<header action="remove" name="connection:close" scope="transport"/>
     <header action="remove" name="connection" scope="transport"/>
     <property action="remove" name="connection" scope="axis2"/>
```

but it's not perfect because I must to modify all the services.
is there a solution how to set this at the wso2 level? is this a bug in wso2 or axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was this problem: https://github.com/wso2/wso2-httpcore-nio/pull/38. now its working

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how the `Connection: Close` header is causing this issue and how removing it from synapse runtime resolves it.

But to answer your question, to intercept requests coming into WSO2 EI you can write a [custom synapse handler](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Working+with+Synapse+Handlers). You can then engage it per service or globally.

On a side note have a look at HTTP tuning parameters as well, https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Tuning+the+HTTP+Transport

Comment: it depends on the system, some call with http header conenction close. configuration of http tuning will not help. wso2 receives a FIN and wso2 must close the connection. close_wait disappears only after wso2 is restarte now.

I can use a handler, but it slows down other calls (only java with a condition)

Comment: If WSO2 is holding the connection that means an ACK was never received for the FIN. This needs some serious debugging to determine what's happening. But what I can't understand is how removing the Connection header resolves the issue. If we assume that the incoming connection header is used to determine the WSO2->BE connection, removing this property will make the BE connection a keep-alive. So I assume this issue is related to the connection between WSO2 and the backend. In tuning parameters, you can globally enable Connection Keepalive. Set that and see whether you see something different.